# Linq DataContext SubmitChanges InvalidOperationException from ZombieCheck

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, datacontext

I am getting an `InvalidOperationException` when trying to add a row using LinqToSql.  We cannot duplicate it in house, and it happens about 0.06% for only one of our customers, always on a relatively simple change to the database.  (Single row insert, or single field update)

```
Message:
   This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.
Stack Trace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Rollback()
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
```

Here is a sample piece of code (the database autogenerates the primary key)

```
TableName row = new TableName();
row.Description = "something";
row.Action = "action";
Context.TableName.InsertOnSubmit(row);
Context.SubmitChanges();
```

We use SQL Server 2008 R2.  The inserts and updates do go through on the server.  But we still get the exception.  There is nothing that should ever prevent these updates and inserts from taking place.  No dependencies or other stuff.

How do we stop these exceptions / zombie checks / rollbacks from happening, or what is causing them in the first place?

**EDIT:**

After further inspection, the database update that being done by the SubmitChanges() is actually occurring.  This exception is getting called after the transaction has successfully completed, and the database row is updated to the new value.

Comment: Is this something that happens only to a specific chunk of code, and if so, is it inside of a `using` block at any point?

Comment: All of our database update functions call a common function to do the DataContext SubmitChanges().  So it always the same line of code that fails.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of is that LinqToSql (and EntityFramework) will by default assign `null` to `DateTime` fields in your data objects, so if your table has a `datetime` field it will throw an exception on insert if the datacontext tries to insert that null value.

You can get around this error by either using the `datetime2` type in MSSQL (which will allow the "null" value of a `DateTime` object - `01/01/0001`) or manually assigning a valid date to the data object's `DateTime` field(s) prior to insert/update.

Without a more detailed stack trace, this is the only obvious problem that comes to mind. HTH.

**EDIT:**

Looks like this isn't entirely uncommon: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/588676/system-data-linq-datacontext-submitchanges-causes-invalidoperationexception-during-rollback#details

The root problem seems to be that the internal ADO logic that LinqToSql uses isn't really configured properly for handling transactional rollbacks. From what I can tell, the only real solution is to provide a transaction object to LinqToSql and manage rollbacks yourself, which doesn't really seem all that appealing.

Comment: No, all fields are filled in.  This happens 0.06% of the time.   The simple updates are the equivalent of Update table set field1='text' where primaryKey=123.  The only other part of the stack trace is my user function that calls the DataContext SubmitChanges() function.